# Select child element jquery img

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good evening everyone. I have some custom checkbox and I'd like to add a css class to them (border: 1px solid red) if I click on one of theme. This is my HTML

```
        <div class="row">
            <div id="format3" class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-centered copertine">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="copertina1" class="copertine">
                        <label  class="copertina" for="copertina1">
                            <img src="img/copertina1.jpg" for="copertina1" alt=""
                            class="immagineCopertina">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-centered copertine">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="copertina2" class="copertine">
                        <label for="copertina2" class="copertina">
                            <img src="img/copertina2.jpg" for="copertina1" alt="">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-centered copertine">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="copertina3" class="copertine">
                        <label for="copertina3" class="copertina">
                            <img src="img/copertina3.jpg" for="copertina1" alt="">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this is the Jquery that I made:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($(':checkbox').on('change', function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('copertine')) {
              $('.immagineCopertina').css( "border", "3px solid red");
            };
        }));
    });
</script>
```

By now if I click on the first element I get the border red, but I need to add this css to the element that I'm selecting. I tried to use

```
($(this).class('.immagineCopertina')).css( "border", "3px solid red");
```

The ($this) element does't work. I think is a syntax. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you want all of the images to get a red border when you select one, or only the image that corresponds to the checkbox you selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what u want to achieve, because didnt see where is that `imagineCopertina` class, but... see that example below and let it discuss...

```js
if ($(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('copertine')) {
      $(this).parents('.copertine').css("border", "3px solid red");
    };
  }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div id="format3" class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-centered copertine">
        <input type="checkbox" id="copertina1" class="copertine">
        <label class="copertina" for="copertina1">
          HERE 1
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-centered copertine">
        <input type="checkbox" id="copertina2" class="copertine">
        <label for="copertina2" class="copertina">
          HERE 2
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-centered copertine">
        <input type="checkbox" id="copertina3" class="copertine">
        <label for="copertina3" class="copertina">
          HERE 3
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you mean is you want to apply the red border to the selected element's image, in which case you could do:

```
$(this).next().children().css("border","3px solid red");
```

in place of the line:

```
$('.immagineCopertina').css( "border", "3px solid red");
```

this way will work if your structure is always the same for your selectable items i.e.:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-centered copertine">
     <input type="checkbox" id="copertina1" class="copertine">
     <label  class="copertina" for="copertina1">
         <img src="img/copertina1.jpg" for="copertina1" alt="" class="immagineCopertina">
     </label>
</div>
```

because it's applying the css style to any children of the label by getting `$(this)` which is currently the checkbox, using `.next()` to go to the label and then `.children()` to get the children of the label. Bear in mind that if you have anything else within label the css will also be applied to that.

If you're trying to apply it to the entire div then do:

```
$(this).parent().css("border", "3px solid red");
```

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwof4nsg/)

You can use jQuery `.parent()` to select the parent of an element.

According to the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

> `.parent()` gets the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements,
>   optionally filtered by a selector.

Change your JS as follows

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   if ($(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
       if ($(this).hasClass('copertine')) {
         $('.immagineCopertina').parent().parent().css("border", "3px solid red");
       };
     }));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things wrong with your code:

1. This line:

   ```
   if ($(':checkbox').on('change', function () {
   ```

   With `.on()`, you are binding a function to the `onchange` event. Like most methods in jQuery, `.on()` is chainable, meaning that it returns the same jQuery collection you executed it on. So the `if` condition on this line is unnecessary and confusing. It should simply be:

   ```
   $(':checkbox').on('change', function () {
       if ($(this).hasClass('copertine')) {
         $('.immagineCopertina').css("border", "3px solid red");
       };
   });
   ```
2. What the code above does is: whenever an element matching the `:checkbox` selector (so any `<input type="checkbox">`) receives the `onchange` event, it checks if the element has the class `copertine` and if so, any element in your DOM matching the `.immagineCopertina` selector (in the HTML you posted, it would only match this element: `<img src="img/copertina1.jpg" for="copertina1" alt="" class="immagineCopertina">`) has its inline CSS `border` property set to `3px solid red`. I'm guessing that's not what you want. I suggest rewriting the code like this:

   ```
   $('.copertine:checkbox').on('change', function () {
       $(this).parent().find('label').css("border", "3px solid red");
   });
   ```

   Notice that I've integrated the check for the `copertine` class in the selector to make the code more compact. Also, I'm specifically styling the `label` element that is a sibling of the checkbox that's checked.
3. There is more work to do if you want to remove the red border when the checkbox is de-checked. You could do something like this:

   ```
   $('.copertine:checkbox').on('change', function () {
       var $label = $(this).parent().find('label');
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $label.css("border", "3px solid red");
       }
       else {
           $label.css("border", "");
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

 $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($(':checkbox').on('change', function () {

            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).parent().css("border", "3px solid red");
            }
            else {
                $(this).parent().css("border", "");
            }
        }));
    });
```